# Where are globals stored in Node.JS? Is there a window-like object in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

If I write:

```
myVar = 123; // note the missing var keyword
```

is there an object in NodeJs where I can retrieve this variable from?

In a browser this would be:

```
window.myVar
```

Comment: Why do you want to do use global variables? I assume you have a reason, but it's worth discussing for the benefit of future traffic to this page.

Comment: I want to test if the Jade template engine is leaking global variables when writing `- myVar = 123` in a template ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node's globals are stored in the `global` variable and is documented [here](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global). Since "global" variables are local to each module, `global` is the true global variable that is shared across modules.

Answer (score 1):

They are stored in the `global` object